# Python: Trying to create n dictionaries with randomly selected values from a range

Tags: python, dictionary, random

So i've tried:

```
import random as r

t = {'va1':r.randint(0,50),'va2':r.randint(0,15),'va3':r.randint(0,10)}
n=15
for _ in range(n):
    new_dict = {k:t for k in range(n)}
print(new_dict)
```

That gave me a dictionary of random dictionaries from t, but they weren't unique, so just a dictionary full of one version of t.

What i'm looking for is a dictionary whose keys are 1,2,3...n and whose values are the dictionary t. But i need t to be different for each iteration of the loop.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't re-run a dictionary literal just because you reference it. `t` is nothing more than that single dictionary you created at the start.

The solution is to create a new dictionary from scratch in the dictionary comprehension (both key and value expressions are executed anew for each iteration):

```
n=15
new_dict = {k: {'va1':r.randint(0,50),'va2':r.randint(0,15),'va3':r.randint(0,10)} for k in range(n)}
print(new_dict)
```

You may want to put creating the nested dictionary into a function:

```
def random_values_dict():
    return {'va1':r.randint(0,50),'va2':r.randint(0,15),'va3':r.randint(0,10)}
new_dict = {k: random_values_dict() for k in range(n)}
```

Note that there is little point in creating a dictionary where the keys are consecutive numbers starting at 0. A list would be more space efficient and have the same performance characteristics mapping such numbers to values:

```
new_list = [random_values_dict() for k in range(n)]
```

`new_list[0]` and `new_dict[0]` both map to a generated dictionary in that case.